# Vertical scrollbar missing in IE11

Tags: javascript, css, handsontable

I love handsontable.  So easy to use and so fast.

But I am stuck right now because I cannot get a vertical scrollbar to appear in IE11.

**Here is the JsFiddle that shows the issue:**

> http://jsfiddle.net/Vaccano/uubL5azk/

If you run that in chrome or firefox you get a vertical scrollbar off to the side.

If you run in it IE11, there is no scrollbar.

The only thing I can think of that is non-standard with my setup is how I position the grid using this CSS:

```
.fill-client{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 130px;
  width: 97%;
  top:190px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Is there something I can change to allow me to use this kind of positioning and still get a scrollbar in IE11?**

Comment: See if this read can help you: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-windows_7/disappearing-scroll-bar-on-websites/c3b883c6-7c46-4749-97af-02ae4b2cef85?auth=1

Comment: @Valius79 - all I could see in there was maybe setting @-ms-viewport.  I tried playing with that css class, but could not find a way to make it affect anything in IE11.

Comment: Alright, set your overflow to auto. That worked for me in IE11.

Comment: @Valius79 - That only allows a fraction of the data to be shown.  Handsontable runs its own scrollbar.  That is why I have overflow set to `hidden`.

Comment: Ok @Vaccano. It looks like the overflow:hidden doesn't work for IE unless the height of the element is specified. I tried setting the height to 300px of the div .fill-client and it works.

Comment: @Valius79 - Yep.  But if I specify a hard coded value, then I loose the resize-ability of my grid.

Comment: Try adding  overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: visible; below your overflow: hidden.

Comment: @Valius79- I don't understand that... It seems to work.  Except the headers scroll too.  I think that is not the Handsontable scrollbar.  If so, then I think I loose UI Virtualization that Handsontable provides (for large datasets).  Still that may be an acceptable workaround.  Thanks for your help!