# Vertical scrollbar missing in IE11 since ExtJS 4.2.4

Tags: extjs

I still have the same problem like Vaccano [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772980/vertical-scrollbar-missing-in-ie11)!
When I use ExtJS greater than 4.2.3 in IE11 there are no scrollbars. I tried 4.2.4 - 4.2.6.

I use a viewport with:

```
launch: function() {
    var vp = Ext.create('ABC.view.Viewport', {
        items:[
            {xtype: 'MyFormPanel'}
        ]
    });
    vp.setAutoScroll(true);
}
```

MyFormPanel has no height and is an anchor-layout. I tried it with other layout but no changes.

Any ideas? (I can´t upgrade to ExtJS 5 at this moment)

**Update:**
Here is a fiddle, but it is not working. I don´t know why.
https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/1ic4

**Answer from Sencha:**

> Blockquote
>   Our lead engineer mentioned that the viewport has simply evolved based on changes needed to work ever changing browser upgrades and the beginnings of device/touch support.
>   A few resources he referenced are detailed here in a separate report:
>   http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html
>   http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html
>   It was not something we just decided to do, but it was done to evolve.
>   This was considerably changed in 6.2 to further evolve with the addition of merging modern/classic into the same framework and provide support for all the possible options.
>   We hope this helps to explain our reasoning for the changes.

Comment: Vaccano doesn't use ExtJS, so the issue is likely completely different. Please make a Sencha fiddle for us to check.

Comment: That want´s the sencha support too, but i can´t create it because it is too "complex". They create a simple fiddle for me that of course worked.

Comment: But if we can't reproduce the issue we can't help you. The issue is somewhere in your code, and we don't have access to that.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: I add a fiddle, but it is not working. I don´t know why.

Comment: I fixed your [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1icc). But i didn't find ExtJS 4.2.4

Comment: @madreason Possibly because you are not logged in with a Sencha Premium Member account (4.2.4 is paid only). I can reproduce the issue in that fiddle, but I don't have enough time right now. I will try to fix it in about 5 hours.

Comment: Thanks @madreason for fixing

Answer (score 1):

For some reason (you have to ask a Sencha official exactly why) Sencha has decided, as of 4.2.4, to insert into the `html` tag the inline style `overflow: auto;`, which was part of the `body` tag before that. It seems as if IE handles the `html` tag differently from the `body` tag.

I didn't find a simple fix with the given component structure, but you can use overnesting to get the component do what you want it to, this worked during my tests at least:

```
var vp = Ext.create('CUN.view.Viewport', {
    layout:'fit',
    items:[{
        xtype:'container',
        overflowY:'auto',
        items: [
            {xtype: 'AngebotErstellen'}
        ]
    }]
});
```

Comment: I will ask Sencha!